# How should we tag Stella Jogakuin Koutou-ka C³-bu?

Tags: discussion, tags

The anime Stella Jogakuin Koutou-ka C³-bu has just recently started airing. I asked a question about it [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/4314/24). The full name is too long for a tag name ([stella-jogakuin-koutou-ka-c3-bu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stella-jogakuin-koutou-ka-c3-bu) would be 33 characters). The English name for the show is "Stella Women's Academy, High School Division Class C³", which is significantly longer than the Japanese name. I haven't seen the English name used in many places.

I used [c3-bu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c3-bu) for now, but it may not be the best abbreviation. I don't know what official abbreviations exist, but it may make more sense to tag as [stella-jogakuin](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stella-jogakuin) or [koutou-ka-c3-bu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/koutou-ka-c3-bu) or some variation therein. We could also make our own abbreviation so long as search engines will catch it.

Answer (score 5):

I think [c3-bu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c3-bu) is indeed the best tag to use, based on these factors:

- There is a 4koma of the series called simply ["4koma C3-bu" (4コマしーきゅーぶ)](http://kc.kodansha.co.jp/content/top.php/1000006352)
- C3-bu is in a noticeably larger font size than the rest of the title on the [manga covers](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/79/Stellawomensacademycover.jpg)
- [English Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3Bu) says C3-bu is a known abbreviation of the title